Can't make an external api call in php side of wordpress child theme
Edited 07-14-24 to show permission callback in api
Edit 2: showed my fatal error
I'm new to making api calls in wordpress. I need to make an api call through the backend to a 3rd party api. I can't do it through the frontend because the 3rd party makes it so I get a CORS error and recommended I make the call through the backend.
I go to my child theme's 'functions.php' file. And I write this code:
function custom_theme_api_init() {

register_rest_route('custom-theme/v1', '/data/', array(
'methods' => 'GET',
'callback' => 'make_api_call_to_third_party',
'permission_callback' => 'custom_theme_api_permissions',    
));

}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_theme_api_init');

function make_api_call_to_third_party() {
$url = 'https://api.pledge.to/v1/organizations';
$api_key = '{my_api_key}';
    
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key\r\n",
        'method' => 'GET',
    ),
);
// Create a stream context
//$context = stream_context_create($options);
// Make the HTTP GET request
//$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    
// Make the API call
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $options);
if ($response === false) {
// Handle error
return false;
}
// Process the response
$data = json_decode($response, true);
return new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
}


and in my frontend, I make a call to the endpoint:
<script>
    const baseURL =  'https://purgace.com/wp-json/custom-theme/v1/data/'; 
    function getOrgs(){
  return fetch(`${baseURL}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data)
      //return renderResults(data.results);

    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
getOrgs();
</script>


However, I am receiving this error:
Object
   code: "rest_no_route"
   data: {status: 404} 
   message: "No route was found matching the URL and 
             request method."
   [[Prototype]]: Object


I think my endpoint could be wrong? I'm not sure. Any ideas on what the problem can be?
I am also now getting a fatal error and it gives me a stack trace:
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given in /home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php:65

Stack Trace
1.  
json_decode(Array, true)
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php:65
2.  
make_api_call_to_third_party(Object(WP_REST_Request))
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php:1230
3.  
WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request(Object(WP_REST_Request), '/custom-theme/v...', Array, NULL)
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php:1063
4.  
WP_REST_Server->dispatch(Object(WP_REST_Request))
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php:439
5.  
WP_REST_Server->serve_request('/custom-theme/v...')
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/rest-api.php:428
6.  
rest_api_loaded(Object(WP))
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:324
7.  
WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:348
8.  
WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/plugin.php:565
9.  
do_action_ref_array('parse_request', Array)
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/class-wp.php:418
10. 
WP->parse_request('')
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/class-wp.php:813
11. 
WP->main('')
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-includes/functions.php:1336
12. 
wp()
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-blog-header.php:16
13. 
require('/home/dh_r54n9h...')
/home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/index.php:17
14. 
{main}
thrown in /home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 65

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! Happy coding :)

did you flush permalinks or turn permalinks off? Your route registration is also missing the permission_callback, it isn't optional and determines who can and can't see/user the REST API endpoint, there'll be a lot of messages about this in your PHP error logs. You also don't need to use json_encode on $response the REST API automatically encodes the data

Hi @TomJNowell thanks for your message! I did not flush permalinks nor turn permalinks off. I also did not include permission_callback. I will give your recommendations a shot! Thanks again!

Actually flushing/resaving permalinks might help! You can also use __return_true as the value for permission callback if you want everyone to be able to use it, saves creating an extra function for it

@TomJNowell thanks for your help! I included the permission callback. However it's still not working. I checked the error logs and i see this message repeatedly:PHP Warning:  Constant WP_CACHE already defined in /home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-config.php on line 7 . Does this have to do with why the api call isn't working? Thanks again for your help!

@TomJNowell im not familiar with flushing/resaving permalinks. Would i do that in the functions.php file?

visiting the permalinks settings page or resaving is enough to do it, rewrite rules aren't generated on the fly there is some pre-processing that's done and stored. I have no idea why you are getting the WP_CACHE warning, and it looks like the warning message is incomplete. I also see that you've made changes but none of the code in the question has been updated

@TomJNowell in the error log, it seems like i keep getting the same php warning over and over. I haven't made any changes to the original code, other than including permission_callback. I don't know if this is important, but my wordpress site is using a child theme. So my front-end makes a call to the functions.php file in my child theme. Is that ok to do?

calling a function that was defined in a child themes functions.php is routine, if it were an issue it would have caused a fatal error and a HTTP 500. When you define something multiple times it usually tells you where it happened as well as where it was first defined. It's extremely unlikely it is related to your question though. I do see that your question hasn't been updated with the latest code, it's unclear what your permission_callback looks like, and we can't see the javascript code that calls the REST API endpoint

you mentioned this code is in a child themes functions.php, are you sure the code actually runs and that you have the child theme activated? The /wp-json endpoint does not list a REST API route with the name custom-theme. I couldn't tell where your themes style.js was from the frontend to check this but I saw you're using Divi (I also notice super weird scrolling on the site, you might want to nuke the smoothscrolling JS)

Hi Tom, thanks for your response! I think the child theme is activated. When i go to purgace.com/wp-json I can see the api route custom-theme/v1. So i think it's being recognized. Do you know how i can console log messages in my functions.php?

ok i think im making some progress haha. I am using error log monitor plugin to see my errors. I get this warning: Warning: Array to string conversion in /home/dh_r54n9h/purgace.com/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php on line 58. I am also getting a fatal error and it gives me a stack trace. Please see my code above

yup I don't think you're using the return value of wp_remote_get correctly, look at the examples on the official docs

Hey @TomJNowell I was able to figure it out! Yea I was not using the response wp_remote_get() correctly. Take a look at my answer if you're curious. I really appreciate your help and guidance! I will also take a look at the smooth scrolling on the site. Happy coding!

So I finally figured out my problems. One mistake I was making was not structuring $options properly.
This is WRONG what i did:
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer $api_key\r\n",
        'method' => 'GET',
    ),
);

I'm not supposed to use http. This is the CORRECT WAY to do it:
$options = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,
        ),
        'method' => 'GET',
    );


You have to use headers instead of http when passing in an api key.
Another mistake I made was improperly getting the response from wp_remote_get().
This is the WRONG WAY:
// Make the API call
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $options);
if ($response === false) {
// Handle error
return false;
}
// Process the response
$data = json_decode($response, true);
return new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
}


using wp_remote_get() like this is correct:
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $options);

However, the way i passed the response into json_decode($response, true) is incorrect. I had to extract the response body like this:
This is the CORRECT WAY:
// Extract the response body
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

// Convert the JSON response to an associative array
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

After i did this, I could access the data from the api response. Here's my correct code in its entirety:
function make_api_call_to_third_party() {
    
    $url = 'https://api.pledge.to/v1/organizations';
    $api_key = '{my api key}';
    
    $options = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $api_key,
        ),
        'method' => 'GET',
    );
    
    // Make the API call
    $response = wp_remote_get($url, $options);
    //handle error section
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
        // Handle the error, return an error response or log it
        return new WP_REST_Response(array('error' => $error_message), 500);
    }
    // Extract the response body
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    
    // Log the response for debugging
    error_log('API response: ' . $body);
    
    // Convert the JSON response to an associative array
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    // Check for JSON decoding errors
    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        // Handle JSON decoding error
        return new WP_REST_Response(array('error' => 'Failed to decode JSON response'), 500);
    }
    
    //process the response
    return new WP_REST_Response($data, 200);
    }

    //function for permissions callback
    function custom_theme_api_permissions(){
        return true;

    }


I was stuck on this for a really long time. So i hope this helps someone out there. Happy coding everyone :)
